# ReferenceError & d3plus not defined

Tags: mysql, express, d3plus

I'm trying to query a MySQL database and create a visualization using d3plus.  My backend is Express.JS and templating is EJS

Here's my error:

```
ReferenceError: C:\cit\views\results.ejs:10
    8| 

    9| <script>

 >> 10| <%   var data = [

    11|      {"year": 2011, "name":"jobs", "value": "2011"}

    12|    ]

    13|    var visualization = d3plus.viz()


d3plus is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\cit\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:618:12), <anonymous>:31:24)
    at returnedFn (C:\cit\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:653:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\cit\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\cit\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:10)
    at View.render (C:\cit\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\cit\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\cit\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\cit\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at Query.con.query (C:\cit\app.js:24:13)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\cit\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
```

My results.ejs code:

```
<% include partials/header.ejs %>
 <h1>= <%= naics %></h1>
 <h1>= <%= industry %></h1>

<div id="viz"></div>

<script>
<% var data = [
     {"year": 2011, "name":"jobs", "value": "2011"}
   ]
   var visualization = d3plus.viz()
   .container("#viz")
    .data(data)
    .type("bar")
    .id("name")
    .x("year")
    .y("value")
    .draw() %>
 </script>

 <% include partials/footer.ejs %>
```

And my header.ejs code that has the d3plus script source:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

</head>

<body>
```

Right now I'm doing a hard copy of the visualization and I'm still getting an issue.  What could the problem be?

PS: I added my script source in my footer, as well.  Just in case that was the issue.  It wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using d3plus v1. Instead, you must using d3plus v2.

`new d3plus.BarChart()
    .select("#viz")
    .data(data)
    .x("year")
    .y("value")
    .groupBy("name")
    .render();`